# running nodejs from USB portably

Tags: node.js, git

[image]

I'm trying to run portable node on my win7 usb E drive. I've downloaded the latest version at https://github.com/garethflowers/nodejs-portable/releases/

I've installed in on my E drive (screenshot)

I added:

```
E:\NodeJSPortable
```

to the PATH env var

But when I type :

```
$ node -v
sh.exe": node: command not found
```

I've restarted my editor and git-bash twice. How can I get this working?

Comment: did you add it to your windows path or your bash path?

Comment: The windows PATH env variable.

Comment: That won’t work for the sh.exe

Comment: Would you please elaborate